# android dagger не получается создать даггер

Tags: android, компоненты, mvp, dagger2, dagger

Всем привет! Есть проект хочу сделать рефакторинг, изменить зависимости используя dagger, до него выглядит вот так

```
public class Activity extends AppCompatActivity implements TrimContractView {

   
    VideoActionPresenter presenter;

......
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity);
     
        VideoActions videoActions = new VideoActions(getApplicationContext(), uri);
        VideoActionsModel videoActionsModel = new VideoActionsModel(videoActions, this);
        presenter = new VideoActionPresenter(videoActionsModel, pinCodeMode);
    }

    .......
}
```

Как мне инициализировать context, uri , activity  и т.д. чтобы они работали в даггер? Может мне поменять схему создания реализации даггера? Может через компоненты или любой другой способ, буду вам благодарен !

> Module

```
@Module
public class VideoActionsModule {


    private final Context context;
    private final Uri uri;
    private final Activity activity;
    private final Constants.PinCodeMode pinCodeMode;

    public VideoActionsModule(Context context, Constants.PinCodeMode pinCodeMode, Activity activity, Uri uri) {
        this.context = context;
        this.pinCodeMode = pinCodeMode;
        this.activity = activity;
        this.uri = uri;
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    Context provideContext() {
        return context;
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    Activity provideActivity() {
        return activity;
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    Constants.PinCodeMode provideConstantsPinCodeMode() {
        return pinCodeMode;
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    Uri provideUri() {
        return uri;
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    VideoActions provideVideoActions(Context context, Uri uri) {
        return new VideoActions(context, uri);
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    VideoActionsModel provideVideoActionsModel(VideoActions videoActions, Activity activity) {
        return new VideoActionsModel(videoActions, activity);
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    VideoActionPresenter provideVideoActionPresenter(VideoActionsModel videoActionsModel, Constants.PinCodeMode pinCodeMode) {
        return new VideoActionPresenter(videoActionsModel, pinCodeMode);
    }
}
```

> Component

```
    @Singleton
@Component(modules = VideoActionsModule.class)
public interface VideoActionsComponent {
    VideoActionPresenter injectVideoActions();
}
```

> App

```
public class App extends Application {

    private static App instance;

    private VideoActionsComponent videoActionsComponent;
  
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        instance = this;
        VideoActionsModule videoActionsModule = new VideoActionsModule(this, pinCodeMode, activity, uri);
        videoActionsComponent = DaggerVideoActionsComponent.builder().videoActionsModule(videoActionsModule).build();
    }

    public static App getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    public VideoActionsComponent getVideoActionsComponent() {
        return videoActionsComponent;
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> Новый MainActivity

```
public class Activity extends AppCompatActivity implements TrimContractView {
    
        @Inject
        VideoActionPresenter presenter;
    
    ......
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity);
         
           App.getInstance().getVideoActionsComponent().injectVideoActions();
}
    
        .......
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Активити в `Application` вы не получите - оно ещё не создано в этот момент. Да и его вообще может не быть.

Если вашим зависимостям нужна активити - создавайте модуль/компонент в активити, не в Application. И не забывайте модуль уничтожать при уничтожении активити.

Вот тут есть пример кода:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/41079553/3212712

Comment: Да, спасибо, ссылка помогла. Подскажите еще при написании теста, что я должен использовать даггер то что в активти    App.getInstance().getVideoActionsComponent().newControllerComponent(new VideoActionsModule(getApplicationContext(),
                pinCodeMode, Activity.this, uri)).inject(Activity.this); или презентер или все вместе ?

Comment: Смотря что тестировать. Тут одного правильного ответа нет.

Comment: Читал, статью, что при использовании даггер легче писать тесты, вы можете какой то пример дать ?

Comment: Ну, там примерно так должно быть при тестировании, например, презентера: у вас зависимости оного можно подменить тестовыми при создании теста. В итоге вы можете программно выдавать те или иные результаты в презентер и смотреть как он реагирует на эти результаты. Подробнее не скажу - не приходилось такие тесты писать и нигде не видел, чтобы их реально писали)

Comment: спасибо понял    !